# Why Clojure's frequencies is not faster than Python's collections.Counter?

Tags: python, performance, clojure

Note - Clojure novice here.

I expected that Clojure implementation of occurrences counter will be significantly faster, than Python one. But it turns out that Python is faster! What is the explanation of this? How one can reason about where Python will be faster and where Clojure will be faster?

I use CPython 2.7.8 and Clojure 1.6.0 with OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_75-b13.

Python code:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
import timeit

DATA = list(ascii_lowercase)*100000

def frequencies(items):
    counter = {}
    for item in items:
        counter[item] = counter.setdefault(item, 0) + 1

    return counter

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: frequencies(DATA), number=1))
```

Output:

```
0.528199911118
```

Clojure code:

```
(ns test
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let
    [data
     (doall (apply concat
                   (repeat 100000 (map char (range (int \a) (+ (int \z) 1))))))]
    (time (frequencies data))))
```

Outputs:

```
"Elapsed time: 861.668743 msecs"
```

### UPDATE #1

I've done some optimization:

```
(ns test
  (:gen-class))

(defn frequencies2
  [coll]
  (into {} (reduce (fn [^java.util.HashMap counts x]
             (.put counts x
                   (inc (or (.get counts x) 0))) counts)
           (java.util.HashMap. {}) coll)))    

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let
    [data
     (doall (apply concat
                   (repeat 10000 (map char (range (int \a) (inc (int \z)))))))]
    (time (dotimes [_ 15] (frequencies data)))
    (time (dotimes [_ 15] (frequencies2 data)))))
```

It outputs:

```
"Elapsed time: 1524.498547 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 476.387626 msecs"
```

So I add two questions:

- Why `clojure.core` [implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/028af0e0b271aa558ea44780e5d951f4932c7842/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6617) does not use type hints?
- How can I optimize performance further? Can I add type hint for hash-map values that are integers?

Comment: The Clojure code is faster on my machine, even without a warmup for the JIT.

Comment: If I am not wrong then I think the Clojure version is much more equivalent to this `reduce(lambda x, y: x + Counter(y), a, Counter())` rather than the one you've posted.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary `frequencies` implemented exactly [like that](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/028af0e0b271aa558ea44780e5d951f4932c7842/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6617)

Comment: @DaoWen What hardware do you use? Mine is old HP G62 laptop with Core i3 chip.

Comment: I'm on an old macbook with a core 2 duo. The Python version consistently comes in at about 768ms, and Clojure at averages around 575ms (tends to jump around ±20ms). A lot of things could probably influence the timings. Which version of Clojure (or Python) you're running, which version of the JVM you're running, etc...

Comment: @DaoWen Updated post with info about versions of languages and implementations.

Comment: Your updated version calls frequencies over a ten-fold smaller data object than the old version. Also, your `data` computation could be shortened / made significantly faster to `(let [ascii-lowercase (char-array "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")] (reduce into [] (repeat 100000 ascii-lowercase)))`. [Don't use concat](http://stuartsierra.com/2015/04/26/clojure-donts-concat). FWIW, the 100.000 version using `frequencies` takes ~554msecs on my machine with the Oracle JDK, whereas the Python version takes 0.449secs, so they're in the same ballpark which isn't what you're seeing.

Comment: @schaueho *Your updated version calls frequencies over a ten-fold smaller data object than the old version.* But I call it along with the old version on the same data.

Comment: If you are really serious about benchmarking Clojure code, you should use Perforate: https://github.com/davidsantiago/perforate

Answer (score 4):

Benchmarking anything on the JVM is a tricky exercise. The JVM will optimise your code as it runs, but it's not easy to predict when this will happen or control it. To get anything more than the most general performance hint between two functions (both Clojure), you need to use a dedicated benchmarking library. [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) is the most commonly used library in the Clojure community for this.

Reasoning about performance is pretty tricky, especially between two very different platforms. I think benchmarking and measuring lots of code will be the best way to develop an intuition between the two languages. Digging in to the underlying data structures and understanding their performance characteristics will help you out. As you've seen in `frequencies2` you can achieve better performance using a mutable HashMap than with Clojure's persistent maps. However you lose all of the immutability goodness if you go that route.

The Clojure version doesn't have type hints for a few reasons.

1. Frequencies is a general purpose function, so it could be dealing with any kind of value.
2. Type **hinting** is only really of performance value for interop with Java **classes**. From [Clojure Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920013754.do), page 367

   > Type hints on function arguments or returns are not signature declarations: they do not affect the types that a function can accept or return. Their only effect is to allow Clojure to call Java methods and access Java fields using compile-time generated code—rather than the much-slower option of using reflection at runtime to search for methods or fields matching the interop form in question. **Thus, if a hint doesn’t inform an interop operation, they are effectively no-ops.** [...] This is in contrast to signature declarations, which Clojure does provide, but only for primitive arguments and return types.

If you are working with exclusively with Java **primitives** in a function, then you can use type **declarations** to optimise it. Again from [Clojure Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920013754.do), page 438

> When Clojure compiles a function, it generates a corresponding class that implements clojure.lang.IFn, one of Clojure’s Java interfaces. IFn defines a number of invoke methods; these are what are called under the covers when you invoke a Clojure function.
>
> **All arguments and return values are Objects at (undecorated) function boundaries.** These invoke methods all accept arguments and return values of the root type java.lang.Object. This enables Clojure’s dynamic typing defaults (i.e., your functions’ implementations determine the range of acceptable argument types, not static type declarations that are enforced by the language), but has the side effect of forcing the JVM to box any primitives passed as arguments to or returned as results from those functions. So, if we call a Clojure function with a primitive argument—a long, for example—that argument will be boxed into a Long object in order to conform to the type signature of the Clojure function’s underlying invoke method. Similarly, if a function’s result is a primitive value, the underlying Object return type ensures that such primitives are boxed before the caller receives the result. [...]

```
(defn round ^long [^double a] (Math/round a))
;= #'user/round
(seq (.getDeclaredMethods (round foo)))
;= (#<Method public java.lang.Object user$round.invoke(java.lang.Object)> 
#<Method public final long user$round.invokePrim(double)>)
```

If you wanted to optimise this further and you were dealing exclusively with Java primitive integers, then you could use the `^int` type declaration for your arguments or return values of functions. However I don't think it would be of any use with your current code. Another route to go down is parallelising the counting and combining them at the end. You could also look at http://java-performance.info/implementing-world-fastest-java-int-to-int-hash-map/ for more ideas, although at that point you're really writing Java in a funny domain specific syntax.

Comment: *However you lose all of the immutability goodness if you go that route.* Notice, that I use `(into {} ...` in `frequencies2` to convert mutable `HashMap` to Clojure `hash-map`.

Comment: What I was getting at is that you will often be able to get better performance in a micro benchmark with mutable objects. If you didn't convert the HashMap back into a Clojure map then frequencies2 would be faster still.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
(set! *unchecked-math* :warn-on-boxed)    ;; clojure 1.7
```

to get warnings by compiler.
Your Update version is fast enough with two warnings:

```
Boxed math warning, /home/.../foo/src/foo/core.clj:68:28 - call: public static java.lang.Number clojure.lang.Numbers.unchecked_inc(java.lang.Object).
Boxed math warning, /home/.../foo/src/foo/core.clj:68:28 - call: public static java.lang.Number clojure.lang.Numbers.inc(java.lang.Object).
```

Here is version with more hints and criterium output:

```
(defn frequencies2
  []
  (into {} (reduce (fn [^java.util.HashMap counts x]
                     (let [^int v (or (.get counts x) 0)]
                       (.put counts x
                             (inc v))) counts)
                   (HashMap.) data)))
```

Criterium:

```
> (bench (frequencies2))
Evaluation count : 720 in 60 samples of 12 calls.
             Execution time mean : 91.375085 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 1.415710 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 89.957446 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 95.135782 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 2.313579 ns

Found 3 outliers in 60 samples (5.0000 %)
    low-severe   1 (1.6667 %)
    low-mild     2 (3.3333 %)
 Variance from outliers : 1.6389 % Variance is slightly inflated by outliers
```

Note that original `frequencies` version is much slower:
`"Elapsed time: 525.264668 msecs"`